# Kivy, changing toolbartitle based on screenname

Tags: kivy, kivymd

How do i change my toolbar title in kivy(md) based on what screen i am on. Ive been able to set the title when im entering the screen, but i also want it to change when im leaving the screen. Why am i not able to set up a while statement in my screenmanager, such as "if screen_manager.current = "screen": toolbar.title = "new title"", or something like that?

For me in Kivy , it seems like i always need a buttonpress or something like that to trigger an event or a change. But i want to know how to set values, such as the toolbar title, without needing a button or something to trigger the change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `current_screen` property, and do something like:

```
class Manager(ScreenManager):
    def on_current_screen(self, sm, screen):
        toolbar.title = screen.name
```

This assumes that `toolbar` is defined somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

So I've solved it by reading more into the binding method. I knew about it before but had only used it for events, didn't know you could use it for when a change was made. I solved it by doing,

self.screen_manager.bind(current=callback)

def callback(self, obj, value) :
If screen_manager.current = "first screen" :
toolbar.title = "some string"
Else:
toolbar.title = "some other string"

And all this code inside a class.